# Read .php file without applying HTML and PHP tags in the result

Tags: php, tags, readfile, plaintext

I need to read a .php file as plain text.

Text in main script:

`<?php $data = file_get_contents('file2read.php'); ?> <pre> <?php echo $data; > </pre>`

For example, I have this in file2read.php:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php> e(enlace('/pages/index', __('index'), True, False, array('class' => 'ajax'))); ?></td>
</tr>
```

The output of the main script is:

> 'ajax'))); ?>

I want that output to be something like this in plain text:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php> e(enlace('/pages/index', __('index'), True, False, array('class' => 'ajax'))); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Read as plain text, or output to a web page in plain text?

Comment: Then simply reading the file does this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using htmlentities()

```
<?php echo htmlentities($data); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read as plain text

```
$data = file_get_contents('file2read.php');
```

Output to a web page in plain text

```
<pre>
   <?php echo $data; ?>
<pre>
```

Comment: Output of this: 'ajax'))); ?>